# Ingresar datos diarios en MYSQL con php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en una app que recibe de 10 a 13 datos y se guardan en una tabla de mi BD, necesito que al completar el dia se sumen esos datos y esa suma se guarde en otro campo de la tabla, estoy usand Laravel 5.5.

este es el controlador:

```
public function show($id)
{
//fechas ingresadas de otra vista
   $fecha1 = DB::table('fechas')->pluck('fecha_inicio')->all();
   $fecha2 = DB::table('fechas')->pluck('fecha_fin')->all();
//fechas convertidas a string       
   $fecha1 = implode($fecha1);
   $fecha2 = implode($fecha2);
//las vuelvo string de carbon
   $primer_dia = (new Carbon($fecha1))->toDateString();
   $ultimo_dia = (new Carbon($fecha2))->toDateString();
//query
   $consumes = consume::where('user_id', $id)
    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$primer_dia,$ultimo_dia])
    ->get();
//vista
   return view('user.consumo.show', [
    'consumes'=>$consumes,
    'fecha1' =>$fecha1,
    'fecha2' =>$fecha2,
   ]);
}
```

Se hace por conteo o por fecha?
recibo sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

te recomendaría que hagas trabajaras en una tarea programada en laravel, esta se puede ejecutar de manera automática todos los días a la hora que tu lo programes.

te dejo la documentación aqui: [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

espero que te sea de ayuda.